# Ionic 2 - How to recalculate margins for scroll-content and fixed-content

Tags: angular, ionic2, auth0

I'm using auth0 lock in my ionic 2 app for authentication. Once authenticated, the user is taken from the login page to the home page. The lock's config is set to `closable: false` to run some code in the background before sending the user to the home page.

However, when I reach home, it turns out that both my `scroll-content` and `fixed-content` are missing inline css for margins. A similar issue has also been discussed here: [Using nav.setRoot causes scroll-content to be missing margins for header/footer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-nav-setroot-causes-scroll-content-to-be-missing-margins-for-header-footer/73853)

Does anyone know how to or what triggers the calculation and insertion of inline css on `scroll-content` and `fixed-content`?

This issue doesn't seem to surface if auth0 lock config has `autoclose: true`, but only happens if you manually hide the lock and proceed to another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `resize` method available at the `ion-content` - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/

All you need to do is:

```
@ViewChildren(Content) content: Content;

headerUpdated() {
  this.content.resize();
}
```

After calling the `resize()` method the margins at `fixed-content` and `scroll-content` would be updated.